# routes not work using jquery ajax calling in mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have a problem when i used custom routes.maps in mvc , when i clicked on login button it show a error 
shown in below

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /ValidLogin**

but when i use `localhost:49257/Admin/Login`, it works properly. `localhost:49257/Admin-login`, it shows error as show above ....

define custom routes below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "admin login",
    url: "admin-login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

public string ValidLogin(string username , string password)
{
    DAOAdmin dao = new DAOAdmin();
    var login = dao.IsValidAdmin(username, password);
    if (login != null)
    {
        return "done";
    }
    else
    {
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

javascript code below

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='btn']").click(function () {
        var dt = $(".fm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ValidLogin',
            type: 'GET',
            data: dt,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.indexOf("done") > -1) {
                    location.replace("admin-section");
                } 
                else if (result.indexOf("failed") > -1) {
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

View Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Vlogin", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "fm" }))
{
    <label for="UserName">Username</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username, new { @id = "txtuserid" })<br />

    <label for="Password">Password</label><br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password, new { @id = "txtpassword" })<br />

    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Login" />
    <span id="result"></span>
}
```

Comment: Change `url: 'ValidLogin',` to `url: '@Url.Action("ValidLogin", "Admin")',` to construct the correct url. I ssupect that `location.replace("admin-section");` may also cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
url: "{controller}-{action}"
```

instead of yours?

Answer (score 1):

```
URL should be like controller/action/id (id is optional)

So, try this:
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "admin login",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

JS file:

$(function () {
    $("input[name='btn']").click(function () {
        var dt = $(".fm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Admin/ValidLogin',
            type: 'GET',
            data: dt,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.indexOf("done") > -1) {
                    location.replace("admin-section");
                } 
                else if (result.indexOf("failed") > -1) {
                }
            }
        });
    });
});enter code here

In View Page, change Vlogin to Login.

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "fm" }))
{
    <label for="UserName">Username</label><br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username, new { @id = "txtuserid" })<br />

    <label for="Password">Password</label><br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password, new { @id = "txtpassword" })<br />

    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Login" />
    <span id="result"></span>
}
```